# Join condition is going wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables as below -

**tbl_confession** -

```
 Confession_id  User_id  title  message
 1              1        new    foo
 2              1        abcd   yes
 4              1        bar    no
```

**tbl_comment** -

```
Comment_id  user_id confession_id  message
1           2       1              foobar
2           2       1              barfoo
```

**tbl_confessionlike** -

```
id  confession_id  user_id
1   1              1
2   1              2
3   2              2
```

**tbl_confessionview** -

```
 id  user_id  confession_id
 1   1        1
```

The expected result should be -

```
 ConfressionId  title  message  total_comments  total_likes  total_views
 1              new    foo      2               2            1
 2              abcd   yes      0               1            0
 4              bar    no       0               0            0
```

The query i am using to achieve above result is -

```
SELECT c.confession_id
      ,c.title
      ,c.message
      ,COUNT(co.comment_id)
      ,COUNT(cl.id)
      ,COUNT(cv.ID)
FROM tbl_confession c
LEFT JOIN tbl_comment co on c.confession_id = co.confession_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_confessionlike cl on c.confession_id = cl.confession_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_confessionview cv on c.confession_id = cv.confession_id
GROUP BY c.confession_id
        ,c.title
        ,c.message
```

Output result -

```
ConfressionId  title  message  total_comments  total_likes  total_views
 1              new    foo      4               4            4
 2              abcd   yes      0               1            0
 4              bar    no       0               0            0
```

But is giving me count as 4 instead of 2. Also, If i want to see the same result per user it remains the same for user_id = 1 but nulls for other users. I am not able to solve the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's giving you count of 4? Which count on which record?

Comment: WFM http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45f718/1

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the problem because you are grouping by the data from the table `tbl_confession`. In your example there is 2 comment, 2 likes, and 1 view that generates `2 * 2 * 1 = 4` records and when you group using the `c.confession_id` in the main query, the `count()` will return 4. I would snuggest to group the records on each of the partial tables  then to join them to the main query, something like this one:

```
     SELECT c.confession_id,
          c.title,
          c.message,
          comment.total_comment,
          likes.total_likes,
          views.totla_views
    FROM tbl_confession c
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
          confession_id,
          COUNT(Comment_id) AS total_comment
          FROM tbl_comment
          GROUP BY confession_id
        ) 
        AS comment ON comment.confession_id = c.confession_id
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT
          confession_id,
          COUNT(id) as total_likes
          FROM tbl_confessionlike
          GROUP BY confession_id
        )
        AS likes ON likes.confession_id = c.confession_id
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT
          confession_id,
          COUNT(id) AS totla_views
          FROM tbl_confessionview
          GROUP BY confession_id
        )
        AS views ON views.confession_id = c.confession_id
    WHERE c.user_id = some_id
```

Comment: I have achieved the same result earlier by putting distinct in count function but the real challenge is to get the same expected column per user by passing a user_id in where clause.

Comment: The expected result i have post it here is the totals of all the tables irrespective of user. If i want to see the same result for a particular User (Suppose user_id = 1), i need to pass that user into where cond. Passing user_id = 1 is giving me the same result while for others is it null. Please let me know if you need some more details on this.

Comment: This is just the sample data. I cannot post the real table here. Actual table have a lot more than this and they do have confession from users other than user_id=1.

Comment: Yes. same result for user_id = 1 and nulls for other user_id.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai maybe I'm asking stupid questions, but it's really strange. If you try to remove the `user_id` condition and add a condition on `where c.confession_id = some_confession_from_user_2` will it returns the correct result

Comment: I think i have some bad DB design. can you please suggest me if there is some change scope.

Comment: actually, I'm not that expert in DB design, for me it looks fine. I'm really surprised from the problem you are facing. Anyway I  have found an error in my query.